# Get DHCP IP with subinterface

Tags: cisco, dhcp, ip-address, packet-tracer, interface

Router0 has 1 subinterface on gi0/0 and can't get a ip trough dhcp. Is there something I forgot?

The configs:

Router0(got no ip from dhcp):

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto

interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0

interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
```

Router1(got ip from dhcp):

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto

interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
```

[image: Network]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two interfaces in the router with addresses in the same network. You didn't define a different VLAN for GigabitEthernet0/0 than the native VLAN, so it will try to get an address in the native VLAN, but you have that defined on GigabitEthernet0/0.1. Routers route traffic between networks, not from a network back to the same network, so your interfaces must be in different networks.

Answer (score -1):

The ports of a router can not be on same subnets

that's why your second port can not get ip from dhcp